# LINQ-to-XML: Find the first security

Tags: c#, linq, c#-4.0, linq-to-xml

I'm trying to optimize my query to only get active companies but not "DEBT." companies.  Also, I need to the data for only the first security.  Here's what my XML string looks like:

```
<DataFeed FeedName="AdminData">
  <Issuer>
    <id>579</id>
    <name>Microsoft</name>
    <symbol>MSFT-NSDQ</symbol>
    <active>1</active>
    <shortName>FirstService</shortName>
    <clientCode>MSFT=US</clientCode>
    <hide>0</hide>
    <securities>
      <Security>
        <id>579</id>
        <rank>0</rank>
        <pricingSymbol>MSFT-NSDQ</pricingSymbol>
        <displaySymbol>MSFT</displaySymbol>
        <active>1</active>
        <clientCode>MSFT=US</clientCode>
        <coverage>
          <Coverage>
            <analyst id="101" clientCode="BG" firstName="Bill" lastName="Gates" rank="1"/>
          </Coverage>
        </coverage>
        <customFields>
          <customField name="ADP Security Code" type="Textbox">
            <values>
              <value>F020941</value>
            </values>
          </customField>
        </customFields>
      </Security>
      <Security>
        <id>581</id>
        <rank>1</rank>
        <pricingSymbol>MSFT-TSX</pricingSymbol>
        <displaySymbol>MSFT-TSX</displaySymbol>
        <active>1</active>
        <clientCode>MSFT=US</clientCode>
        <customFields>
          <customField name="ADP Security Code" type="Textbox">
            <values>
              <value>F020941</value>
            </values>
          </customField>
        </customFields>
      </Security>
    </securities>
  </Issuer>
  <Issuer>
    <id>558</id>
    <name>Apple</name>
    <symbol>AAPL-NYSE</symbol>
    <active>1</active>
    <clientCode>AAPL=US</clientCode>
    <hide>0</hide>
    <securities>
      <Security>
        <firmId>18524</firmId>
        <id>558</id>
        <rank>0</rank>
        <pricingSymbol>AAPL-NYSE</pricingSymbol>
        <displaySymbol>AAPL</displaySymbol>
        <active>1</active>
        <clientCode>AAPL=US</clientCode>
        <coverage>
          <Coverage>
            <analyst id="129" clientCode="SJ" firstName="Steve" lastName="Jobs" rank="1"/>
          </Coverage>
        </coverage>
        <customFields>
          <customField name="ADP Security Code" type="Textbox">
            <values>
              <value>F106997</value>
            </values>
          </customField>
        </customFields>
      </Security>
    </securities>
  </Issuer>
  <Issuer>
    <id>612</id>
    <name>Tesla</name>
    <symbol>DEBT.TSLA</symbol>
    <active>1</active>
    <clientCode>DEBT.TSLA</clientCode>
    <hide>0</hide>
    <securities>
      <Security>
        <id>613</id>
        <rank>0</rank>
        <pricingSymbol>TSLA-NYSE</pricingSymbol>
        <displaySymbol>TSLA</displaySymbol>
        <active>1</active>
        <clientCode>DEBT.TSLA</clientCode>
        <coverage>
          <Coverage>
            <analyst id="101" clientCode="EM" firstName="Elon" lastName="Musk" rank="1"/>
          </Coverage>
        </coverage>
        <customFields>
          <customField name="ADP Security Code" type="Textbox">
            <values>
              <value>G002869</value>
            </values>
          </customField>
        </customFields>
      </Security>
    </securities>
  </Issuer>
</DataFeed>
```

Here's what I have so far for my query:

```
var xDoc = XDocument.Parse(xmlString)
.Descendants("Issuer")
.Where(xd => (int?)xd.Element("active") == 1 && (int?)xd.Element("hide") == 0 && 
    !xd.Element("clientCode").ToString().StartsWith("DEBT.")
    )
.Select(xd => new { 
    Ticker = xd.Element("clientCode").Value,
    Symbol = xd.Element("symbol").Value,
    DisplaySymbol = xd.Element("displaySymbol").Value,
    AnalystFName = xd.Element("Analyst").Attribute("firstName").Value,
    CompanyName = xd.Element("name").Value,
    ADP = xd. <-- not sure what to do here
});
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

I think the problem is that I can't seem to get only the first security.  How do I get the info needed for only the first security.  Also, how do I get the ADP code?  I'm having a hard time trying to figure the code out for that.  In the end, I'm trying to get the following results:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

`Element` only gets the immediate child elements, you need `Descendants` at certain points here.

You can probably do this in a prettier fashion with some refactoring into smaller composable chunks, but this would get the job done on your sample file:

```
var rows =
    from issuer in doc.Descendants("Issuer")
    let ticker = (string) issuer.Element("clientCode")
    let symbol = (string) issuer.Element("symbol")
    where (int?) issuer.Element("active") == 1 &&
          (int?) issuer.Element("hide") == 0 && !ticker.StartsWith("DEBT.")
    from security in issuer.Descendants("Security").Take(1)
    from analyst in security.Descendants("analyst")
    from adpField in security.Descendants("customField")
    where (string) adpField.Attribute("name") == "ADP Security Code"
    select new
    {
        Ticker = ticker,
        Symbol = symbol,
        DisplaySymbol = (string) security.Element("displaySymbol"),
        AnalystFName = (string) analyst.Attribute("firstName"),
        AnalystLName = (string) analyst.Attribute("lastName"),
        ADP = adpField.Value
    };
```

See [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Po9gtO) for a working demo.